# No context menu when right clicking textarea

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following `textarea` defined in a Firefox addon, which renders fine ..

```
<tr>
    <td align="right">
        <div data-l10n-id="fileName_title"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
        <textarea id="fileName" rows="1" cols="20"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
```

When I right click on this `textarea`, no context menu is shown, why not?
Here is `javascript` which is loaded into page.
But does not interact with `filename`.

```
window.addEventListener('click', function(event) {

    if (event.target.id.indexOf('pathToFile') == 0){

        alert('path');

    } else if (event.target.id.indexOf('saveButton') == 0){

        alert('saveButton');

    }else if (event.target.id.indexOf('cancelButton') == 0){

        alert('cancelButton');  
    }

}, false);
```

Comment: well is there an error in the console? and what happens when you click on an element that has no id? :) `if (!event.target.id) return;`

Comment: It [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/rotsee/gbrjxk50/), what error do you get?
http://jsfiddle.net/rotsee/gbrjxk50/

Comment: No, there is no error in console. If I click an element with no `id`, nothing happens, as expected.

Comment: Ubuntu > Chromium browser. I am getting the context menu on right click, and the javascript code gets triggered on left-click. Is this what you are not able to get or are you looking for something else. Cheers.

Comment: I want to show the context menu when right mouse button is clicked, normal behaviour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be a bug with `addon-sdk` .. https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=858399